# Convert UNIX timestamp into Data - iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, date, nsdate, unix-timestamp

I have an iOS application which parses a JSON feed for data. In this data are some UNIX timestamps which I am storing in a NSString. What I want to do is to convert these timestamps into dates (month and day). But I am trying to do this without doing any division myself, because from what I have read online, you should always use Apple's API's to do the conversion for an accurate result.

However my code is not working and I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here is my code:

```
NSString *time_string = [timestamps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:time_string];

cell.dateOfPub.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Can you show us the results of `NSLog(@"%@", time_string)`?

Comment: @Kamaros The output is: 1359269613

Comment: Ah. Yeah, `dateFromString` assumes you're passing in a string like "2013-10-16" rather than a time interval. Incmiko's got the right answer, though the date format is different from the one you wanted.

Comment: The error indicates that your `timestamps` array has `NSNumber` objects, not `NSString` objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double unixTimeStamp = [time_string doubleValue];
NSTimeInterval _interval=unixTimeStamp;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *_date=[_formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `time_string` variable is actually referencing an `NSNumber` object (based on the error message). This code only works because both `NSString` and `NSNumber` have a `doubleValue` method.